# What is the full chronology of the ages in the Dark Crystal franchise, and how do all the different works fit in them?

Tags: suggested-order, dark-crystal

From perusing the Dark Crystal fandom wiki I think all the 'dietetic' ages are:

1. Age of Innocence
2. Age of Harmony
3. Age of Division
4. Age of Power

With the Original movie and Age of Resistance taking place in the Age of Division, and The Power of the Dark Crystal taking place in the Age of Power.

But it seems like there's a lot of other media out there set before, after or during those stories.

Are these all the ages, and if so what works of fiction take place in each?

Comment: When I look at the entries for the various ages in https://darkcrystal.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Ages , I notice that in many of them the references at the bottom clearly refer to the various comics etc. Why not start a community answer with the information you've already collected from those, allowing others to edit in additional info?

Comment: I think the *Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance* takes place in the Age of Resistance, at a guess.

Comment: @BCdotWEB because try as I might, I did not find that page. You're welcome to start a CW if I don't get there first.

Comment: @Adamant as far as I can see, and if the wiki is correct, that's not an actual 'Age' dietetically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](https://darkcrystal.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Canon_Dark_Crystal_media) seems to answer that question, grouping the various comics etc by Age (and even in subdivisions inside an Age where appropriate).

## 1 - Age of Innocence

- The Dark Crystal: Creation Myths #1

## 2 - Age of Harmony

- The Dark Crystal: Creation Myths #2
- The Dark Crystal: Creation Myths Vol. 2 #1 - #2

## 3 - Age of Division

- The Dark Crystal: Creation Myths Vol. 2 #3 - #4
- The Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance (comic book) #1 - #9
- [The Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance Tactics](https://darkcrystal.fandom.com/wiki/The_Dark_Crystal:_Age_of_Resistance_Tactics#Plot)

### 3.1 - Age of Sifans

- The Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance (comic book) #10 - #12
- The Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance (TV series) SO1E01 - SO1E03

### 3.2 - Gelfling Resistance

- The Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance (TV series) SO1E04 - SO1E10

### 3.3 - End of Garthim Wars

- The Dark Crystal (movie)

## 4 - Age of Power

- The Power of the Dark Crystal #1 - #2

### 4.1 - Return of the Skeksis

- The Power of the Dark Crystal #3 - #12

## 5 - Second Age of Harmony

- Beneath the Dark Crystal #1 - #12

---

This YouTube video also appears to attempt to provide a reading order:

If you look at its notes, its reading order includes even more books (e.g. novelization of the movie etc.).